# auto create posts from pdfs

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf

I have several hundred pdf's that I need to put up as seperate posts on my clients website, and I was wondering if anyone could point me in the direction of the code I would need (or need to write) in order to do this automatically. Preferably, the code would be able to take a folder or zip file, and generate posts from the pdf's located in the folder and subfolders. It would create a category hierarchy based on the the names of the folders, and post titles based on the titles of the pdf's. Each post would contain a link to the pdf and an embedded version of the pdf using the google docs viewer code. An exmple post can be seen here . If it could also auto generate a menu that would be great, but it isn't as vital. So, any thoughts?
Also, here is the code that a friend helped me to put together as a start:

```
$directory = '/path/to/files/';
$filter = '/*\.pdf$/i';        // Filename ends in .pdf or .PDF
processDirectory($directory, $filter);

function processDirectory($directory, $filter) {
if (substr($directory,strlen($directory)-1,1) != '/') { // Add trailing /
    $directory .= '/';
}
if ($handle = opendir($directory)) {
    /* This is the correct way to loop over the directory. */
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if (is_dir($directory.$entry) {
            // Recurse into nested directory
            processDirectory($directory.$entry, $filter);
        } else if (preg_match($filter, $entry)) {
            echo "Processing file $directory/$entry<br />\n";
            // Valid filename: Build post
            // Contents of $post array described in http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post
            $post = Array(
                'post_content' => ' <a href="http://somesite.com/$directory/"' . $entry . '">' . $entry . '</a>.<br />'.
                                  '<iframe src=http://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url=' .
                                  urlencode($directory.$entry) . '></iframe>',
                                  // This won't be right! You'll need to convert $directory and add your website domain
                'post_title' => $entry
            );
            // Post post
            wp_insert_post($post);
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "Failed to open $directory";
}
}

?>
```

Comment: hmmm.- I once wrote a plugin to do that for all doc types ( images, .doc, pdf ..) I will have to find it . But what is the problem in the code you have now ??

Comment: it doesn't currently actually do anything, or at least I don't know how to make it do anything. Going through and trying to debug it and ensure it includes all the correct code for Wordpress to Acknowledge it

Comment: I'm curious whether you found a resolution. I am interested in performing the same task.